# T-SQL String Functions: difference between using Left/Right and Substring and strange behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 & 2005 (Express). I'm trying to extract part of an alpha numeric string from a varchar field.

`RIGHT(str_field, 3)` yields null values but `SUBSTRING(str_field, LEN(str_field)-2, LEN(str_field))` gives the right value. `LEFT(str_field, 7)` gives the expected values.  What gives?

I would have thought that `RIGHT(str_field, 3)` and `SUBSTRING(str_field, LEN(str_field)-2, LEN(str_field))` are equivalent expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have trailing spaces

RIGHT will yield spaces but LEN ignores trailing spaces

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(100)
SET @foo = 'abc12345def   ' --3 spaces

--right or substring
SELECT RIGHT(@foo, 3)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@foo, LEN(@foo)-2, LEN(@foo))

--demonstrate you get spaces
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@foo, 3), ' ', 'z') --single space

--length differences
SELECT LEN(@foo), DATALENGTH(@foo)

--solution
SELECT RIGHT(RTRIM(@foo), 3)
--or trim your column values before storing
```

See [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Note: you *won't* get NULL for non NULL input...

```
--only NULL if you send in NULL
SELECT RIGHT(NULL, 3)
```