# Trimmining a column with bad data

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

My data looks like

```
ID    LPNumber 
1     30;#TEST123
2     302;#TEST1232
```

How can I update MyText to drop everything before the # and including the #, so I'm left with the following:

```
ID    LPNumber 
1     TEST123
2     TEST1232
```

I've looked at SQL Server Replace, but can't think of a viable way of checking for the ";"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CHARINDEX(), LEN() and RIGHT() instead.

```
RIGHT(LPNumber, LEN(LPNumber) - CHARINDEX('#', LPNumber, 0))
```

Comment: If trailing spaces are stored (`SET ANSI PADDING ON` is by default) this will bollix you because LEN trims these first. There is method is my apparent madness...

Comment: @gbn - I never doubted your madness :)

Comment: @JamesKhan - Heed gbn's comment before using this answer.

Answer (score 6):

On the [MSDN REPLACE page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), the menu on the left gives the complete list of string functions available.

```
UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
   LPNumber = SUBSTRING(LPNumber, CHARINDEX('#', LPNumber)+1, 8000);
```

I'll let you work out (from MSDN) the filter needed in case there is no `#` in the column...

Edit:

Why 8000?

The longest non-LOB string length is 8000 so it is shorthand for "until end of string". You can use 2147483647 too for max columns or to make it consistent.

Also, LEN can bollix you.

- [`SET ANSI_PADDING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) is ON by default
- `LEN` ignores trailing spaces

You'd need to use DATALENGTH but then you need to know the data type because this counts bytes, not characters. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557843/27535 for example

So using a magic number is perhaps a lesser evil...

Comment: +1 : beaten by 22 seconds.  I need faster fingers!  :)  *[Although, does this hold for VARCHAR(max)?]*

Comment: @aF. - Ooooh, I don't think it's nice to alter some-one elses answerunless it's for Typos etc.  The reason for 8000 would be that it's suitable for everything other than VARCHAR(max) afaik, and would seem to be deliberate to me.  If you disagree with that, do make a comment or even your own answer, but to edit the answer?  Ooooooh...

Comment: @aF. is `CHAR_LENGTH` SQL Server function? I can't find it.

Comment: @Dems: change to 2100000000 if you want

Comment: @aF.: 8000 is a quick way to say "until end of string" given non-LOB max string length is 8000. If you use MAX (LOB) types, then you can use 2100000000 or 2000000000. Using LEN is pointless, really, and IMO makes it cluttered. Rolled back your edit: I know what I'm doing...

Comment: @Dems omg and I edit to wrong :P I went to the len of sybase and not sql ^^

Comment: @gbn ok m8 :) don't be offended :P

Comment: Hehehe `I know what I'm doing`.  Lovely :)  Merry Christmas everyone.

Comment: LPNumber = missing from SET statement . Otherwise works a treat. Thank u, you are truly gifted.

Comment: @aF. - You did alter his answer instead of putting forward your view as another answer or comment.  It was a little rude and presumptuous...

Comment: @Dems I won't do it anymore :P

Comment: @all: added explanation and fixed UPDATE. Cheers

Comment: Now, that's an effing answer! :)

Comment: I'd say LEN *ignores* trailing spaces, not *removes*, but then it's you who speak English as the first language, not me...